# PHP mkdir with form input and security

Tags: php, html, mkdir

I'm trying to make the folder with mkdir but no success, I can see that the path is correct but $_post isn't getting the name of folder from form input ($_post['foldername' is empty) don't know what's the problem. (I have all the permissions to make the folder safe_mode is off

Comment: Try using $_POST (case matters)

Comment: Variable names in PHP are case-sensitive.  Also, a) using user input to affect stuff like filesystem entities is a really bad idea, and b) you're not checking the success or otherwise of the mkdir call, just assuming it works.  Never assume operations that can fail have succeeded.

Comment: Boy, I hope your usernames aren't allowed to include characters like `../anotherUserName` or `../../../etc`.

Comment: WHY USING USER INPUT IS BAD IDEA?

Comment: @Arshsingh Because you don't know who the user is.  You should assume that they mean to be malicious.  Even accidentally someone could submit malicious inputs that cause all sorts of issues.  You should not trust it, it should be cleansed and filtered.  http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Schleis SO WHAT SHOULD I USE ,,, i'm making the folder inside surrently loggedin user's folder , through form input $_post method.

Comment: IT'S A BAD IDEA BUT THERE'S NO NEED TO YELL ABOUT IT.

Comment: Make sure that the foldername doesn't include '..' in it, since you are prepending a path you don't have to worry about '/' and them trying to get access to your base directories.  As @DarkDust pointed out, you want to make sure that they don't try to use relative paths.

Comment: no one can user relative paths ( with login or without login) they are only accessible via server account  --- @Schleis  please post your openion as answer so i will accept it ,, i corrected the mistake by myself ,,, wanted to accept your answer for giving me right suggestions

Comment: @Arshsingh: You need to _always_ check the user input, especially when you use it to construct paths, commands, SQL queries, etc. You must always assume that someone sends you a malicious command. For example, I could construct an HTTP call and give a `foldername` that looks like `../../../../../../etc/something`, and boom you have a directory `something` in `/etc` to which everybody is allowed to read or write (assuming that your web server is allowed to write to `/etc` but you should get the point: I can make your script into places you didn't intend.

Comment: @DarkDust can u please send me the modeifed link of http call so i can test and try to secure my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$_POST` to get the filename.

As has been posted in the comments, you also need to do something with `$_POST['filename']` to insure that the user is not trying to post a relative path to your script and trying to create folders in locations that you don't intend.  At the very least make sure that the variable doesn't contain '..'  Since you are prepending a path, I don't think that you have to worry about a direct path to '/' but you may also want to invalidate inputs with a '/' in them.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try this:

```
<?php  
include("models/db-settings.php");
include("models/config.php");

$foldername = $_POST["foldername"];  
$filename   = $foldername;
$path       = __DIR__ . "/uploads/" . $loggedInUser->username;
$fullPath   = $path . "/" . $filename;
if (!file_exists($fullPath)){  
    mkdir($fullPath, 0777);  
    echo "The directory was successfully created.";  
}  
echo $fullPath;

?>

<form action="mkdir.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="foldername" id="foldername" value="FolderName">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You're making the same mistakes as the OP

Comment: @GordonM No, I am not, the OP asked why its not working, not how to add validation. The reason this does not work is because the path was not the full path, also down voting peoples comments because you think your comment is correct is not the best approach. BTW I corrected the variable name.

Comment: It's not working because he put $_post instead of $_POST.  At least that's probably one of many reasons why it's not working.

Comment: @GordonM if you have an answer for the OP why not add one instead of criticizing everyone else's, also perhaps you should refresh the page before actually commenting to see any changes.

Comment: @Bloafer: Think about what happens when I make a POST and pass `../../../../../../etc/something` for `foldername`.

Comment: @DarkDust I understand the security problems with this solution, but that's not what's in question at the moment. Yes by all means I would advise against using this solution in a production environment

Answer (score -4):

Change

```
if (!file_exists($path)) {  
        mkdir("$path/$filename", 0777);  
        echo "The directory was successfully created.";  
    }
```

to

```
if (!is_dir($path)) {  
        mkdir("$path/$filename", 0777);  
        echo "The directory was successfully created.";  
  }
```

Comment: And please dont create a folder from a name generated by `$_POST()` in my own opinion it is dangerous consider `XSS`

Comment: @Temitayo so what should i do ,,, i need to make the folder with name that i want i don't want to make the folder name in mkdir function so im using $_post

Comment: Let me ask, what are you trying to test with file_exists()

Comment: I think you need to edit your question for clarity and also, if you want to check if a directory exists you use is_dir() not file_exists()